# Help on extending root partition on extended file system

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

The following is the current partitioning on my friend's Ubuntu machine.Here, `/dev/sda5` is root file system. This is located on extended file system.  I want to add the `80GB ext4` (`/dev/sda3`) and `250GB` unallocated to root (`/dev/sda5` - `ext4`).
I am able to extend only 80GB `/dev/sda3`. But could not extend `/dev/sda5`. Even with live cd, I have to delete both `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda2` to extend but that's resulting grub error. How can I achieve it without losing data? [image]

Comment: Partitions must be unmounted to work on them from live cd/USB.  Best way to not lose data is backup data.  Data lost should be expected when working on partitions.

Comment: yeah, correct. Atleast I want the machine to boot up after changes.

Comment: Don't mention Ubuntu version, so after backup if wanting to upgrade just install newer version with partitions you want.

Comment: Move /dev/sda3 to the end of the unallocated space.  Then grow (resize) /dev/sda2.  Then /dev/sda5 can be resized after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it from live CD(USB) in this order:

1. If there are any data on `sda3` you want to keep, back them up first.
2. delete `sda3`
3. select the extended partition `sda2` and grow it's size to the most right.
4. select `sda5` and grow it's size to the most right.